Question regarding max and min of function when derivative cannot be 0
This question is in regards to finding the range of the following function
$$x^3 - x^2 + x + 1$$
I decided to find the maxima and minima of this function by computing its derivative, the derivative of the above function is,
$$3x^2 - 2x + 1$$
The thing is this function can never be $0$ as it does not have real roots. The answer to the above question is give to be the whole real number line i.e. $R$.
My question is whether in any situation when the derivative cannot be $0$, the function's range is $R$.
Could someone please verify this for me
Any help would be appreciated!

What about $f(x) = x$ ?

The range of $\arctan$ is $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, but $\arctan'$ is never $0$.

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that every polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ (possibly complex) roots (with multiplicity). For example, your polynomial $3x^2 - 2x + 1$ will have $2$ (not necessarily distinct, and not necessarily real) roots. I'm not sure this is relevant to the heart of your question, but it's still worth pointing out. (If you meant it has no real roots, perhaps you could add that information.)

@Kyle It is irrelevant because here only real roots are of interest.

Recall that critical points only correspond to local extrema in general!

If the function is differentiable and the derivative is never equal to zero it will not have any local max, min.  But that does not mean it has unbounded range.  Take a function a function whose values that is bounded between $-1< f(x) < 1$ so that as $x\to \infty$ $f(x)\to 1$ (assymptotic) and as $x\to -\infty$, $f(x)\to -1$.  I think the function I am imagining is actually $f(x) = w\arctan x$ where $w = \frac 1{\frac \pi 2}$.  but any function with those assymptotes and a monotonic graph will do.

I think you are assuming if a function has no maximum (or minimum), it can't ever have a greatest (or least) value. That is true. And you are think therefore for every value it achieves it will achieve a larger one (again true) and therefore all values will be achieved. That is false. The function may have a supremum, an upper bound never achieved.  for example $f(x) = 1-\frac 1x$ as no max (if $f(x)=M; k> 0$ then $f(x+k) > M$) but no matter how large it gets it's always $<1$.  ... but such a function requires the derivative to approach zero.

Maybe we should point out that if we have a case of $\arctan$ were the derivative is never $0$ but the function is bound between values, that the function (if continuous and differentiable everywhere) is asymptotic, and that means although the derivative is never $0$ it will approach zero.  And although there are no achieved max/min there approached sup/infs.  One can think, informally, of a sup/inf ans an unachieved max/min, and corespondingly, they occur where the derivative is an "unachieved $0$"

To summarize earlier comments: the derivative can help you find a local maximum or minimum, but those are not guaranteed to correspond to the range of the function: consider $f(x)=x^3-x$; but on the other hand you can have a function that has a finite range but never exactly reaches the upper or lower limit of its range and therefore has no local minimum or maximum. So if all you know is whether the derivative is ever zero, you cannot conclude anything about the range of the function.

If the function is differentiable and the derivative is never equal to zero it will not have any local max, min. But that does not mean it has unbounded range. Take a function a function whose values that is bounded between $−1<f(x)<1 $so that as $x→∞$, $f(x)→1$ (assymptotic) and as $x→−∞$, $f(x)→−1$. I think the function I am imagining is actually $f(x)=w\arctan x$ where $w=\frac 1{\frac π2}$. but any function with those assymptotes and a monotonic graph will do.
I think you are assuming if a function has no maximum (or minimum), it can't ever have a greatest (or least) value. That is true. And you are think therefore for every value it achieves it will achieve a larger one (again true) and therefore all values will be achieved. That is false. The function may have a supremum, an upper bound never achieved. for example $f(x)=1−\frac1x$ as no max (if $f(x)=M;k>0$ then $f(x+k)>M$) but no matter how large it gets it's always $<1$. ($f(x)< f(x+k) < f(x+2k)<.... < 1$) ... but such a function requires the derivative to approach zero.
Maybe we should point out that if we have a case of $\arctan$ were the derivative is never $0$ but the function is bound between values, that the function (if continuous and differentiable everywhere) is asymptotic, and that means although the derivative is never $0$ it will approach zero.  And although there are no achieved max/min there approached sup/infs.  One can think, informally, of a sup/inf ans an unachieved max/min, and corespondingly, they occur where the derivative is an "unachieved $0$"

The function $f(x)=x^3-x^2+x+1$ is an odd degree polynomial, which means that it verifies: $f(-x)=-f(x)$. clearly $\lim_{x\to\infty}=+\infty$ so it's range is $(-\infty,+\infty)$ 
the derivative of $f(x)$ is $3x^2-2x+1$ does not have real roots, you put it greater than $0$ anyways:
$$f'(x)\geq 0\Rightarrow (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\geq0$$ by studying the intervals in which you function is increasing you can find the range. As for your other question if the derivative is always $>0$ not necessarily the range is $\mathbb{R}$ for example: $\arctan{x}$ is an always increasing and convex function whose range is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$
